# 'NoneType' object is not iterable возникает ошибка в парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Во время парсинга выходит такая ошибка.For t in t Это я хотел спарсить ссылку.

```
import json
 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 

def wr_json(lst: list):
    with open('save.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(lst, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
 
 
URL = 'https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/' 
HOST = 'https://krisha.kz' 
 
def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return r

 
def get_content(html,):

    response = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    cards = []
    inc = response.find('.a-card__inc')
    for i in inc:

        link = i.find('.a-card__title', first=True).links
        cards.append({
                      'name': i.find('.a-card__title', first=True).text,
                      'price': i.find('.a-card__price', first=True).text,
                      'description': i.find('.a-card__text-preview',first=True).text,
            })
        for t in t:
 
            cards.append({'Floor': t.find('div', class_='offer__advert-short-info'),
                         'Square': t.find('div', class_='offer__advert-short-info'),
                         'State': t.find('div', class_='offer__advert-short-info'),
                         'Year': t.find('div', class_='offer__advert-short-info'),
                         'ComplexHome': t.find('div', class_='offer__advert-short-info'),
                         'SellerDescriphion': t.find('div', class_='offer__parameters'),
                         'Description': t.find('div', class_='a-text a-text-white-spaces'),})


    return cards 
 
def parser():

    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:

        cards = []
        for page in range(1,):

            print(f'Парсим страницу: {page}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'page': page})
            cards.extend(get_content(html.text))
        print(cards)
        wr_json(cards)
    else:

        print('Error')
 
 
parser()
```

Comment: ну так вы до цикла не создали переменную `t`, что он должен интерировать. и не называйте разные переменные одним и тем же именем

Comment: Создал переменную на t,но теперь выдает   for title in title:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'title' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/'

res = requests.get(url)
response = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
inc = response.select('.a-card__inc')
for i in inc:
    name = i.select_one('.a-card__title').text
    price = i.select_one('.a-card__price').text.strip()
    print(name)
    print(price)
```